# Send command to Putty (Windows)

Tags: perl, dos, putty

I need to send Putty a command after I do the following:

```
Putty.exe -ssh HOST@ADDRESS_1
```

Due to issues with ADDRESS_2 I can't access it directly after launching Putty. Instead I need to do the following after launching Putty:

```
ssh HOST@ADDRESS_2
```

Then I can get to ADDRESS_2.

Is there a way to send a command for putty to run after it launches. I looked up and putty does have a -m switch, however I was unable to get it to work on my Windows system.

Comment: If you set up a "saved" connection that does what you want, you get more options, and can specify it on the command line with `putty -load [connection name]`

Comment: It needs to be a universal method so that I won't need to save any sessions prior to running it. That's why I'm using ssh instead of load in the command.